# .htaccess rewrite with a default language specified

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make an .htaccess rewrite on the webpage.

Only these two language are available *[en, it]* and *[en]* is the default one.

Here's a list of examples to be more clear and detailed:

```
http://website.com -> http://website.com/en
http://website.com/en -> http://website.com/en
http://website.com/it -> http://website.com/it
http://website.com/de -> http://website.com/en
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=[a-z]{2}(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|it) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2}/)?(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you! last thing: what if i wanna make this thing on the second parameter? index.php?lang=$1&page=$2

Comment: thanks a lot, we're almost there, i just have a redirect loop now

Comment: Ok I realized what's the problem, fixed it by adding a new RewriteCond in first rule. Please check.