# base or relative path don't work on a .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, path, redirect

With an .htaccess I'm rewriting an url in this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=[a-z]{2}(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|it) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2}/)?(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

to follow this conditions:

```
http://website.com -> http://website.com/en
http://website.com/en -> http://website.com/en
http://website.com/it -> http://website.com/it
http://website.com/de -> http://website.com/en
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079854/htaccess-rewrite-with-a-default-language-specified/) for more info about that.

Now the problem is when I have to access to some assets. For example, I have to load *css/styles.css*

I tried to change the base location to give an absolute path by adding the base:

```
<base href="http://website.com/">
```

or by setting a relative path by putting:

```
../css/styles.css
```

The browser ask for the files in the right way:

```
Request URL:http://website.com/css/styles.css
Status Code:302 Found
```

But I get no files and the response headers are:

```
Location:http://website.com/en/css/styles.css
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to not redirect your assets. Depending on how you have your site working, you can either exclude requests for certain directories or exclude requests for resources that exist (like a file or directory):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=[a-z]{2}(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|it) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2}/)?(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=[a-z]{2}(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|it) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2}/)?(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: the first solution is perfect! is there a way to include the /css/ folder and all its subdirectories at once? i also have some problems..it works with css but not with other files like imgs or js, i get a 404